# C# Datacontext in class library

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, migration, class-library

I thought it would be nice to move my database classes out of a NET.Core project into a class library.

I had a class called `ApiRegistrationDataContext`, inheriting from `DbContext` and a class `ApiRegistrationSqliteDataContext`, inheriting from `ApiRegistrationDataContext`.

In the ASP.Core-project I had some lines regarding the database classes in file `Startup.cs` and in a service. I would create a migration via `Add-Migration SomeName -Context ApiRegistrationSqliteDataContext -OutputDir Migrations\ApiRegistrationSqliteMigrations`.

Now I moved those classes into a class library and removed all connections from the ASP.Core project. However now I cannot create a new Migration (I was able to move the old migration from the ASP.Core project to the class library).

The error message reads

```
Unable to create an object of type 'ContactDataContext'. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728
```

which is honestly no help at all.
Why did it work in the ASP.Core project but not in my class library anymore?

Comment: Have you added all the NuGet packages (that deal with EF) that your original project has to your class library?

Comment: Are you invoking the command from package manager console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dbcontext-creation) state:

> Some of the EF Core Tools commands (for example, the Migrations commands) require a derived DbContext instance to be created at design time in order to gather details about the application's entity types and how they map to a database schema.

So after your changes EF can't do it. One of the options would be to create `IDesignTimeDbContextFactory` inside of the corresponding project:

```
public class ApiRegistrationSqliteDataContextContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<ApiRegistrationSqliteDataContext>
{
    public ApiRegistrationSqliteDataContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
    {
       var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ApiRegistrationSqliteDataContext>();
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlite("Data Source=blog.db");

       return new ApiRegistrationSqliteDataContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
    }
}
```

Also if you are using VS package manager console to work with migrations make sure that you have set correct startup project (in solution explorer) and default project (in package manager console).

Also try to run Add-Migration specifying `Verbose` flag:

```
Add-Migration SomeName -Context ApiRegistrationSqliteDataContext -OutputDir Migrations\ApiRegistrationSqliteMigrations -Verbose
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this solved my problem perfectly and saved me a lot of more headache

Comment: @user3079834 was glad to help!