# ASP.NET Core : Why do we need IDesignTimeDbContextFactory?

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-6.0

I have an ASP.NET Core application and all I have is the `DataContext`, I don't have `IDesignTimeDbContextFactory` implemented.

```
public class DataContext : DbContext, IUnitOfWork
{...}
```

With that I can do `Add-Migration`, `Update-Database` & `Script-Migration`.

However, I came across an another project where they have implemented `IDesignTimeDbContextFactory`, mentioned that this is to generate migration classes.

```
public class DesignTimeDbContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<CodingBlastDbContext>
{
    public CodingBlastDbContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
    {
        IConfigurationRoot configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
            .Build();

        var builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<CodingBlastDbContext>();

        var connectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");

        builder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);

        return new CodingBlastDbContext(builder.Options);
    }
}
```

I wonder why this is needed? especially the first project works without implementing the `IDesignTimeDbContextFactory`..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/dbcontext-creation?tabs=dotnet-core-cli#from-a-design-time-factory) have some explanation on when you can leverage the design-time factory:

> A design-time factory can be especially useful if you need to configure the `DbContext` differently for design time than at run time, if the `DbContext` constructor takes additional parameters are not registered in DI, if you are not using DI at all, or if for some reason you prefer not to have a `CreateHostBuilder` method in your ASP.NET Core application's Main class.

The only use case I personally encountered was when `DbContext` was moved into a separate library and we did not want to run `CreateHostBuilder` for context designing purposes (startup involved some relatively heavy stuff and we didn't want to invoke that). Like for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62120631/2501279).